# How to stream H264 with gstreamer?

Tags: android, gstreamer, h.264

I need to stream my screen in fullHD, to my android phone with gstreamer, using H264. I'm using [gst launch remote](https://github.com/sdroege/gst-launch-remote) on Android and `gst-launch` on linux.

I'm starting with gstreamer, I managed to do basic stream following [this tutorial](http://www.einarsundgren.se/gstreamer-basic-real-time-streaming-tutorial/), but anything a bit different from the examples crashes on various ways.

My basic pipeline is:

```
ximagesrc use-damage=false xname=/usr/lib/torcs/torcs-bin ! videoconvert ! x264enc tune=zerolatency ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=192.168.0.100 port=5000
```

And:

```
udpsrc port=5000 caps=$CAPS ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! autovideosink
```

I tied to copy the caps from the first pipeline (all or multiple combinations of isolated parameters) to `$CAPS` but didn't work.

With

```
caps="video/x-h264\,\ codec_data\=\(buffer\)01f40028ffe1001a67f400289196401e0089f89c0440000003004000000ca3c60c9201000668ebcc448440\,\ stream-format\=\(string\)avc\,\ alignment\=\(string\)au\,\ level\=\(string\)4\,\ profile\=\(string\)high-4:4:4\,\ width\=\(int\)1920\,\ height\=\(int\)1080\,\ pixel-aspect-ratio\=\(fraction\)1/1\,\ framerate\=\(fraction\)25/1"
```

the pipeline isn't constructed, the only error is:

```
WARNING: erroneous pipeline: could not link udpsrc0 to rtph264depay0
```

Or with caps

```
application/x-rtp\,\ media\=\(string\)video\,\ clock-rate\=\(int\)90000\,\ encoding-name\=\(string\)H264\,\ packetization-mode\=\(string\)1\,\ payload\=\(int\)96\,\ a-framerate\=\(string\)25
```

The error is:

```
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0: Internal data flow error.
```

Error message witout caps:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_0_39
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Got context from element 'autovideosink0': gst.vaapi.Display=context, gst.vaapi.Display=(GstVaapiDisplay)NULL;
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpH264Depay:rtph264depay0: No RTP format was negotiated.
Additional debug info:
gstrtpbasedepayload.c(484): gst_rtp_base_depayload_handle_buffer (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpH264Depay:rtph264depay0:
Input buffers need to have RTP caps set on them. This is usually achieved by setting the 'caps' property of the upstream source element (often udpsrc or appsrc), or by putting a capsfilter element before the depayloader and setting the 'caps' property on that. Also see http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-good/tree/gst/rtp/README
Execution ended after 0:00:00.006279687
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

Comment: Can you explain what changes you made to pipeline that crashed it?

Comment: This pipeline is a modification from the codecs in the tutorial to h264, it isn't working even in localhost. I updated the question with some error messages

Comment: I had seen similar error with some other plugins. This generally happens if cap negotiation fails. Just try to do gst-inspect on udpsrc and rtph264depay and see if you can feed information about the caps so that cap negotiation does not fail.

Comment: Could you try setting caps `video/x-h264, stream-format=byte-stream` for your `x264enc` element?

Comment: I changed the source to a webcam and worked! However it doesn't work with FullHD, but I will make a separate question for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the source video from a web solved the caps negotiation issue. The final pipeline was:

```
v4l2src ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=1600,height=1150 ! x264enc tune=zerolatency ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=192.168.0.100 port=5000
```

And:

```
udpsrc port=5000 caps = "application/x-rtp, media=video, clock-rate=90000, encoding-name=H264, payload=96" ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! autovideosink
```

Thought, bigger resolutions are crashing the app.